# How Did They Do That?? Vol. 2: Ghostbusters “proton pack”

Tags: iconic-sounds, film-sound-design, creativity

Following on from Jay Jennings' post, [How Did They Do That?? Vol. 1: The Predator “clicks”](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/how-did-they-do-that-vol-1-the-predator-clicks), I thought I'd carry on the series with another classic, iconic sound - the Ghostbusters Proton Pack powering up. If anyone knows how it was done, please share your wisdom with us. And if there are any other Ghostbuster related sound knowledge why not share it here too. To give you a taster, check the video. There's a good example when they are in the lift (1min51sec).

[youtube]nJ0lE01alik[/youtube]

Comment: It sounds like a pitched up helicopter turbine, don't you think?

Comment: I also think it sounds like a turbine being switched on and then the stereo image is thrown out of phase.  I recorded some jet engine race cars in North Carolina a while back and they sounded exactly like this.

Comment: @Justin @Matthew It could well be a turbine in their but it'd be great to get some real confirmation. Anyone know of any articles out there on the sound of Ghostbusters?

Comment: @Jay I thought it'd been a while since ur post on the Predator clicks and Ghostbusters is a classic!

Comment: To be honest, it sounds like a low boom like an electric generator being switched on, then a regular oscillator flipped up to about 6K. Then maybe even an elevator or truck's back lift. Be interesting if anyone finds the true data!

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty confident its a turbine with added synth filtered.

Answer (score 2):

The sound is created by the magnetron as it heats up the proton flux. 
It is not an unpleasant sound but quieter models are now available that can generate signifcntly more GeV with virtually no noise at all. This is due to the discovery of plasma based magnetic fields.